# Concatenate elements of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation, nested-loops

I haven't found a solution to my specific issue on here, so here goes. I want to scrape news article metadata from different searches on the news site. I did this before for a single search, running the code over all the search result pages.

Here is my code:

```
 urls = ["url1&page=", "url2&page=", "url3&page="]

 for url in urls:

    for page in range(2):

        browser.get(url + str(page))
```

What I want to achieve is that it goes through all the page numbers for all the urls, but I get "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list".

The desired output would be: "url1&page=0", "url1&page=1", "url2&page=0", "url2&page=1"... FYI I have about 10 urls like this and the range is 20 pages.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: here's the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b0fdd2b9dc7f> in <module>
     15     for page in range(21):
     16 
---> 17         browser.get(url + str(page))
     18         #browser.get(f'{url}{page}')
     19 

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Edit 2: thanks @balderman and @darkknight, it worked! I had another label called 'url' further down which was causing some additional issues but luckily I spotted it quickly :) Now looking at a beautiful csv of my data, thanks again!

Comment: `browser.get(f'{url}{page}')` can do the job here

Comment: Please show the full stack trace

Comment: Please, show the full traceback, exactly as you get it. I guess it's a typo - using `urls` instead of `url` in concatenation.

Comment: We appreciate you trying to make a [mcve], but this code does not seem to exhibit any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
NPAGES=2
urls = ["url1&page=", "url2&page=", "url3&page="]
for p in range(NPAGES):
  for url in urls:
    browser.get(f'{url}{p}')
```

Comment: I re-read the question and edited my answer accordingly